# Как узнать о переходе на новую строку при вводе из файла?

Tags: c++

Как узнать о переходе на новую строку при вводе из файла?

Answer (score 1):

Можно считывать например так...

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
char c;
FILE *bu=fopen("input.txt","r");
int i=0;
while (c!='\n') {
      fscanf(bu,"%c",&c);
      i++;
      }
fclose(bu);
return 0;
}
```

Но многое зависит от того, а что же такое конец строки... Концом может быть например вот такая комбинация #13#10 (в шестндцатиричном виде), т.е перевод на следующую строку и сдвиг каретки влево, в начало строки. Либо может быть просто #10. Для разных ОС характерны разные варианты завершения строки. 
В примере fscanf, по пока не понятным причинам, пропустил символ r (код #13) и перешёл сразу к n (код #10). То есть мы выждали при чтении появления n и вышли =)

Answer (score 0):

Смотря как читается файл. Если посимвольно, то сравнивать считанный символ с символом перехода на новую строку '\n'. Если побайтно, то сравнивать с соотв. последовательностями байт ( разные на разных ОС ). А можно и просто сразу по строкам брать с помощью getline.

Comment: Вот у меня получается, что при использовании оператора >> автоматически пропускаются всякие \n.

Comment: Если вводятся, например, числа из не форматированного файла, то никак.

Answer (score 0):

n - символ перехода на новую строку

Comment: то есть строка **canon** занимает 3 строчки? :)

Comment: нет. имелся ввиду символ '\\n'

Answer (score 0):

Читая, посимвольно проверять каждый символ на `'\n'`, если символ равен `'\n'`, то засчитать еще одну строку.